# Is it possible to alias a long code line?

Tags: c#, .net

The following line of C# code is frequently used in a project:

```
((DataGridRow) TicketGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(SelectedRow - 1)).Background = ...;
```

Is there any way to alias this to something like this?

```
TicketRow.Background = ...;
```

Comment: A property in your ?form? that calls this?

Comment: Perhaps a property or an extension method which sets the proper value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just wrap it in a method:

```
void SetBackground(TicketGridsType ticketGrid, PropertysType value)
{
    ((DataGridRow) ticketGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(SelectedRow - 1)).Background = value;
}
```

Which you would then call like so:

```
SetBackground(TicketGrid, ...);
```

---

You could always turn it into an extension method by wrapping it in a static class, making it static and changing the signature to:

```
public static void SetBackground(this TicketGridsType ticketGrid, PropertysType value)
```

then call

```
TicketGrid.SetBackground(...);
```

Comment: I should have thought of this! Too busy trying to think outside the box :)

Comment: Yep, firmly inside the box :)

Comment: if you want you can also tell the compiler to try to make this method (SetBackground) "inline" using the attribute `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` found in the 
`System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace